# Making Highcharts.js charts look good on mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, responsive-design

I'm wondering if anyone has successfully implemented a responsive design using Highcharts to make their charts look good on both mobile and desktop.

By default, Highcharts do re-scale when you resize the browser screen its just that the X-axis get cluttered by the tick mark text and bar graphs look tall and too skinny (too compressed).
To get a sense of what I mean, you can go to [this page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic) and resize the browser.

I think these issues could possibly be addressed by reducing the amount of data points say to 1/3 of the original number though I'm wondering how that would be accomplished programmatically using Highcharts's API. If that doesn't sound like a good idea I'm also interested in other thoughts or solutions people might have come up with to use Highcharts on mobile (or perhaps even different JS charting libraries where a multi-device solution might be easier to implement?).

Comment: Refer to this and see if it helps - http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/qheh4w0n/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution seems rather simple.

Just don't give the graph's a fixed width, i.e., don't define the width or set `width:100%` and, unlike the demo I mention, the bar chart width and accompanying bars will shrink as much as the browser width is reduced.

Answer (score 4):

It probably depends on which types of charts that you are displaying. On mobile, if you're displaying a column chart, you might want to rotate the chart so that it becomes a bar chart.

If you're displaying a line chart, you could "scope" the data, so that you're only displaying the least amount of points needed to get the point across. As you zoom in, re-scope the data to fit the current view. This can be done using some events combined with some hand rolled js.

Comment: It isn't likely to be a one-solution-fits-all is indeed the point. You're going to have to tell the computer what you want done @TimPeterson and not let it just guess for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the chart container div `width:100%` .
Then just remove the highchart width property. I resolved it for a sparkline chart. Now it is mobile responsive.

```
Highcharts.chart('my-sparkline-chart, {
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline',
            height: '70',
            //width: '189', //comment width property.
            spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

An Example with bootstrap

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Highcharts data from JSON Response</title>
        <style>
        body{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left:40px;
        }
        .col-md-4{
        padding-left:5px !important;
        padding-right:5px !important;
        }
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>    
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       // Data gathered from http://populationpyramid.net/germany/2015/

// Age categories
var categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
        '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
        '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
        '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
        '95-99', '100 + '];
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },

        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, { // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: [-2.2, -2.2, -2.3, -2.5, -2.7, -3.1, -3.2,
                -3.0, -3.2, -4.3, -4.4, -3.6, -3.1, -2.4,
                -2.5, -2.3, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, -0.0, -0.0]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [2.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 2.9,
                3.1, 4.1, 4.3, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 2.9, 2.9,
                1.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.0]
        }]
    });
     Highcharts.chart('container2', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Population pyramid for Germany, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://populationpyramid.net/germany/2015/">Population Pyramids of the World from 1950 to 2100</a>'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, { // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: [-2.2, -2.2, -2.3, -2.5, -2.7, -3.1, -3.2,
                -3.0, -3.2, -4.3, -4.4, -3.6, -3.1, -2.4,
                -2.5, -2.3, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, -0.0, -0.0]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [2.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 2.9,
                3.1, 4.1, 4.3, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 2.9, 2.9,
                1.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.0]
        }]
    });
     Highcharts.chart('container3', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Population pyramid for Germany, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://populationpyramid.net/germany/2015/">Population Pyramids of the World from 1950 to 2100</a>'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, { // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: [-2.2, -2.2, -2.3, -2.5, -2.7, -3.1, -3.2,
                -3.0, -3.2, -4.3, -4.4, -3.6, -3.1, -2.4,
                -2.5, -2.3, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, -0.0, -0.0]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [2.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 2.9,
                3.1, 4.1, 4.3, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 2.9, 2.9,
                1.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.0]
        }]
    });
})

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12 row">
<div class="col-md-4">
hello
</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><div id="container" style="height: 400px;border:1px solid;"></div></div> <div class="col-md-4"><div id="container2" style="height: 400px;border:1px solid;"></div></div> 
  <div class="col-md-4"><div id="container3" style="height: 400px;border:1px solid;"></div></div>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this on the `<head></head>`

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```